# Преобразование принятого ответа в комментарий

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, модерация, ответы, инструменты-модератора

При попытке преобразовать принятый ответ в комментарий движок отправляет на страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/error

Пошагово:

1. Открываем [Отображение русских букв шрифта Myriad Pro в Google Chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175069/)
2. Жмем `мод -> преобразовать в комментарий -> 175069 - Вопрос -> Отправить`
3. Случилось страшное! Попадаем на страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/posts/175074/convert-to-comment , котэ негодует.

Comment: Новости по багу есть?

Comment: Новостей по багу больше не будет!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ преобразовался без проблем... Если снова заметите эту ошибку, дайте знать здесь в комментах, пожалуйста.