# Наш сайт тормозит

Tags: поддержка

Собственно, вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сегодня ru.stackoverflow.com часто тормозит при отправке комментариев, открытии вопросов и т. д.

Кто допустил котов к разработке?

Comment: Меня аж разлогинило при этом.

Comment: а сегодня это когда?

Comment: @Grundy на момент публикации поста и коммента моего. Я тоже котейку словил такого.

Comment: пока не воспроизводилось

Comment: Не ловил. Возможно, уже прошло?

Comment: Думаю, проблема уже решена. Собственно, я создал тему, чтобы котейку всем показать.

Comment: Котик давно [тут живёт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/170/176217).

Comment: Фиксирую ту же проблему последние 20 минут.